# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException in java

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jdbctemplate, csv-import

I have below java class where i am trying to import the data from `CSV` file and insert into oracle database table..

When i am trying to run this java class i am getting error as 'java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException'. I just try to see the insert statements using `log.info("Insert values to table" +sql);`and i can see some insert statement are generated and then its throwing an error.

I am quiet new to java so not sure how to handle this exception.

Below is my code:

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what line is causing the error - could you include the line number or your stack trace? However, this worries me:

```
for (int i = 0; i < headings.size(); i++) {
                String columnName = headings.get(i);
                String value = columns.get(i); // <- this
```

You are iterating with `i` through `headings.size()`, but what if `headings.size()` is greater than `columns.size()`? Then your program will try to access an index of `columns` that does not exist, which would give you an *IndexOutOfBounds* exception.

Comment: can you please tell how to do that ? how to put stack trace ?

Comment: Could you copy/paste the message (modify your question, format it nicely) your compiler gives you when you try to run the program? The part that says "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException" when you attempt to run your code.

Comment: i have formated code and also put log message in for loop you mentioned ...after this value its getting failed ...Value:  Mandamus Capital Limited, Dublin 2 ...i have added complete error code now

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure what this means. Rather than fix each error as we go, I recommend you **start over from scratch, one small step at a time**. This seems like a relatively complex task that would give anyone some trouble, let alone someone who is new to Java.

Comment: actually i thought this is not much complicated as may be i need to correct the for loop or some index value as the error indicated everything

Comment: i just need some hints or where i can handle this exception

Comment: i checked in Arraylist.class where this method is mentioned...if (index >= size)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));